# MySql select last timestamp of each hour

Tags: mysql

I need to select the last "close" value of every hour in a table. I have seen other answers to this question but non of them seem to work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT a.mydate, b.`close`
FROM (
  SELECT max(t.`date`) AS mydate
  FROM yourTable t
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.`date`,"%Y%m%d%H")
) a
LEFT JOIN yourTable b ON a.mydate = b.`date`
ORDER BY a.`date`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This works for selecting the last timestamp for each hour, however the close value is wrong for some reason.

This query returns:
2009-05-08 11:59:00 - 1.504595

The real data is:
2009-05-08 11:59:00 - 1.50721

Comment: It returns correctly if i take away max() but i obviously need that to get the last timestamp of the hour

Comment: @Jay P - i have change my answer - please test again

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Bernd Buffen's answer. His query correctly selected the last timestamp of each hour, however the close values where wrong. My query below selects the close value correctly.

```
SELECT table1.close
FROM `GBPUSD_minutes` table1
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT max(`date`) as last FROM `GBPUSD_minutes` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,"%Y%m%d%H")
) table2
  on table1.date = table2.last
WHERE `date` > '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND `date` < '2010-01-30 00:00:00'
```

Thanks to Bernd Buffen for giving me

```
DATE_FORMAT(`date`,"%Y%m%d%H")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM mytable t1
WHERE t1.`date` = (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM mytable t2
  WHERE DATE(t1.`date`) = DATE(t2.`date`) AND HOUR(t1.`date`) = HOUR(t2.`date`)
);
```